# core_config_data and core_url_rewrite table truncated

Tags: magento1.9.2.3

I have a Magento 1.9.2.3 website running in Nginx and MySQL . in which is `core_config_data` and `core_url_rewrite` table auto-truncated.

it is not happening a fixed time interval. sometimes its happening in the morning sometime in the evening and sometimes in the night. how to find the root cause of it. I have tried all the possible solution but no luck.